# Angularjs show/hide and alternating styles

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of divs that display information about products.  The core information is the same, but certain fields are only shown or hidden (via ng-show/ng-hide) for certain product type.   This works fine, but we want to show rows in alternating styles (zebra stripes) for readability.  How can do this since if I hide one row we will end up with two rows with the same style?  The HTML is of the form:

```
    <div style="alt-1">
       <div class="col-md-3 list-item-odd">Location</div>
       <div class="col-md-9 list-item-odd" >{{ location }}</div>
   </div>

   <div ng-show="itemType == 1" style="alt-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 list-item-odd">Layout Type</div>
      <div class="col-md-9 list-item-odd" >{{ layoutType}}</div>
   </div>

   <div style="alt-1">
      <div class="col-md-3 list-item-odd">Category</div>
      <div class="col-md-9 list-item-odd" >{{ category }}</div>
  </div>
```

As this example show if the itemType != 1 we end you with two adjacent rows with the style "alt-1".

One idea I had was to write a directive (alternate-styles in the example below) with a lower priority to walk DIVs after ng-show (or ng-hide) complete.

```
<div class="enclosing" alternate-styles>

       HTML from above

</div>
```

However, there are two things that bother me.  One, will it work.  I am always surprised by something in Angular.  Two, I have this nagging suspicion that I am letting my jQuery experience blind me to the obvious Angular solution.

Opinions and/or suggestion?

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: Could you make use of ng-repeat and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassEven?

Comment: I thought about that, but then I would have to create a large array of fields and prompts and then fill each section of the form dynamically.  It is an option, but not one I prefer to use since it is  different than all of the other layouts in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the directive to work was kind of challenging for me since I'm new to Angular. I was fighting the entire time with ng-show firing after the custom directive (a way after).
I did find this [blog](http://ruoyusun.com/2013/08/24/a-glimpse-of-angularjs-scope-via-example.html), which explained why ng-show has the behavior I was experiencing.
Here is the java script snippet for the custom directive and the controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.location = 'location here';
  $scope.layoutType = 'layoutType here';
  $scope.category = "category here"
  $scope.itemType = 2;
  $scope.alternateStyle = 0;
});
app.directive("alternateStyle", ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('itemType', function(newVal) {
          $timeout(function() {
            if (!element.hasClass('ng-hide'))
              scope.alternateStyle++;
            if (scope.alternateStyle % 2) {
              element.removeClass('alt-1').addClass('alt-2')
            } else {
              element.removeClass('alt-2').addClass('alt-1')
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

and here is the working [sample on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSmoSexsMTe4sFD7P3Eb?p=preview)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This is just what I need.  The key to my understanding was the bit about detecting ng-hide.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Angular 1.2, then you can use [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) in place of `ng-show/ng-hide` to completely remove the element from the DOM.